# Can "which" refer to a part of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

> When he went to Japan to meet his friends, he **bowed a little** to them instead of having handshakes, **which** is the Japanese way of greeting people.

Is this sentence correct?

It seems that the "which" refers to the action of bowing a little.

Can "which" refer to a part of a sentence like this?

Comment: Yes, supplementary relative clauses can refer to virtually anything. In your example, the preceding clause "he bowed a little to them" is the antecedent of "which". We understand that R is the Japanese way of greeting people, where R is interpreted as his bowing a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it certainly can. However that sentence is actually ambiguous, because without context, *which* is more likely to refer to the more recent "having handshakes" than to the earlier "bowed a little". But grammatically it is fine.